# Python regex doesnt match 1 occurrence with 0 or 1 occurrences operator?

Tags: python, regex

I have date strings of the following forms
'8 april 2022', '8 april', 'april'
and a regex to try and match any of them

```
re.findall(r"(\d{1,2})?.*(januari|februari|maart|april|mei|juni|juli|augustus|september|oktober|november|december).*(202\d)?", str)
```

the problem is, it will return `('8', 'april', '')` in case of `str = '8 april 2022'`
so my question is: why does `?` ignore 1 occurrence of `202\d` when its there?
Thank you.

EDIT. With non greedy `.*?`

```
re.findall(r"(\d{1,2}).*?(januari|februari|maart|april|mei|juni|juli|augustus|september|oktober|november|december).*?(202\d)?", str)
```

it still doesnt capture 2022

EDIT 2. Considering the answers a better question would be:
Is there a way of saying 'hey regex 1 occurrence is optional but preferable to 0' ?

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/6FydPf/1 or perhaps like this if there can not be any other digits in between? https://regex101.com/r/sIemKW/1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to ignore anything in between (like woensdag) thats not 'day' 'month' or 'year'. I have a working solution already, I just want to understand whhy `?` prefers 0 occurrence to 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` should be rarely used due to the **greediness** `.*` after matching `month` is matching **too much** and not leaving anything to match in 3rd capture group for year. Also you just need to match 1+ spaces between strings. It is important to make part between month and year *optional* by using a non-capture group as shown below.

You may use this regex with non-optional matches, word boundary and bit of tweaking:

```py
\b(?:(\d{1,2}) +)?(januari|februari|maart|april|mei|juni|juli|augustus|september|oktober|november|december)(?: +(202\d))?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Iqrsf/1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But even when its non greedy `.*?(202\d)?` it still ignores 2022.
PS. Sorry for not mentioning this but sometimes i have a string like `3 mei woensdag 2022` or more spaces between the match groups so thats why i'm using .*

Comment: If you note I have used  ` +` which will match 1 or more spaces

Comment: I have added more explanation on what's wrong in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` matches `" 2022"` and then the `(202\d)?` matches `""`, as it's optional and there's nothing left.

The `.*?` matches `""` and then the `(202\d)?` matches `""`, as it's optional and the remaining `" 2022"` doesn't even start with `2`.

You wish it would search further so that the `(202\d)?` matches the `"2022"`, but why should it search further? It already found a match, so it stops and reports that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you by any chance know if there is a way of saying '1 occurrence is optional but preferable to 0' ?

Comment: @Sev I don't really see the essence. If you prefer 0 occurence, why not simply remove the year pattern to exclude it completely?

Comment: No its the opposite. I prefer 1 occurrence to 0 occurrences, but want to have a match even with 0.

Comment: To quote: ```'1 occurrence is optional but preferable to 0'```. Or did I misunderstand your statement?

Comment: @Sev You could use ` *` (that's supposed to be a space and an asterisk, sadly SO doesn't format that correctly) instead of `.*`.

Comment: If with *"1 occurrence is optional but preferable to 0"* you're talking about the `?` in `(202\d)?`: That's already how it behaves. What makes it "fail" there is the context, the combination with `.*`, as described in the answer.

Comment: @JoboFernandez yes you probably misunderstood the statement.

Comment: @KellyBundy thank you for the explanation. As I said it ignores 2022 even when I use .*? instead of .*

Comment: @KellyBundy you wrote in the answer ' The .*? matches "" and then the (202\d)? matches "" ', it seems that ? kind of prefers nothing to something. I was wondering if there is an opposite

Comment: @Sev No, it prefers something to nothing. But where it's asked to match, it *can't* match something, only nothing. If you give it the chance to match something, it will. Like with my suggestion to use a space.

Answer (score 1):

On the last part of your regex pattern `.*(202\d)?`, the 2022 is captured by the `.*` and consequently `(202\d)` captured nothing.

This is for your perusal, but may not be exactly as you wanted.

```
matches = re.findall(r"(?:\d{0,2}\s*)(?:januari|februari|maart|april|mei|juni|juli|augustus|september|oktober|november|december)(?:\s202\d)?", str)
```

For `3 mei woensdag 2022`, this may not be what you wanted exactly but it should work for the year:

```
matches = re.findall(r"(?:\d{0,2}\s*)(?:\w+\s*)+(?:\s*202\d)?", str)
```